# Delivering video stream from IP cameras

Tags: c#, video-streaming, ip-camera

I have several IP cameras. I want to get their streaming video but using an additional server to centralize the cameras. This server should get the video stream from 2-5 cameras and then, deliver it again through a different url. thereby many streaming users wouldn't overload the IP cameras which can not hold a high number of viewers.

It the first time I'm facing video streaming that's why I'm a bit lost and I don't know where should I begin from. I've any restrictions about which protocol use, rtsp, http... I'm quite free about that.

I've found [this project](http://net7mma.codeplex.com/) which looks like pretty similiar to my problem. Anyway, before going deeper in it, I would like to have the opinion of someone who has develop anything similar before. Any tip would be apreciated.